# How to get the row values from a Table in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Am new to PHP coding kindly help me.
Here is my code:

```
echo "<td id=\"row\" align=\"center\">" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id=\"title\" align=\"center\">" . $row['Title'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id=\"prodname\" align=\"center\">" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id=\"amt\" align=\"center\">" . $row['Amount'] . "</td>";
$amt = $row['Amount'];
echo "<td id=\"row\" align=\"center\">" . 
     "<select id=\"testing\" onchange=\"GetSelected (this,$amt)\">
        <option value=\"100\">100g</option>
        <option value=\"250\">250g</option>
      </select>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Add\">" . "</td>";
```

Once I clicked the Add button I need the row values to be stored in an array or a variable.

Comment: Use form and submit it, you will get the values in `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Enclose the fields in a form, and just store those values in hidden fields, so that it'll get submitted to serverside on clicking submit button.

Comment: plz explain.what u want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code it this way

```
<form name="frm" method="POST" action="">
 <table>
  <tr>
echo "<td id=\"row\" align=\"center\">" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id=\"title\" align=\"center\">" . $row['Title'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id=\"prodname\" align=\"center\">" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id=\"amt\" align=\"center\">" . $row['Amount'] . "</td>";
$amt = $row['Amount'];
echo "<td id=\"row\" align=\"center\">" . 
     "<select id=\"testing\" onchange=\"GetSelected (this,$amt)\">
        <option value=\"100\">100g</option>
        <option value=\"250\">250g</option>
      </select>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=\"SUBMIT\" value=\"Add\">" . "</td>";
  </tr>
 <table>
</form>
```

Now you can have the array as **$_POST** or **$_REQUEST**

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code may help you to solve your problem.

Place this code in your PHP script

```
 <? php
   if ( $_GET["reg"] == "suc" )
   {
     $row['id']=$_GET["id"];
     $row['Title']=$_GET["title"];
     $row['prod']=$_GET["prod"];
     $row['amount']=$_GET["amt"];
   }
   else
   {
   echo "try again";
   }
  echo "<form action=\"?reg=suc\" method=\"GET\">\n";
  echo "Id: <input name=\"id\" ><br />\n";
  echo "Title: <input type=\"text\" name=\"title\" ><br />\n";
  echo "Productname: <input name=\"prod\" ><br />\n";
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="amt" value="100" >';
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="amt" value="250" > ';
  echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Add\">\n";
  echo "</form>\n";
 ?>
```

If u click Add button those values will be stored in array
U can POST method instead of GET to send those value in hidden way !!!